# Haskell inline-c-cpp call Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I am using inline-c-cpp in a small example to reverse a String:

```
[C.block| void {
        static char strTest[128] = "Hello, Haskell!";
        c_func();
  } |]
```

The Haskell code are:

```
reverseIO :: BS.ByteString -> IO BS.ByteString
reverseIO str = return $ BS.reverse str
```

`c_func()` is defined in another c file that I included by `C.include "test.c"`
In that `test.c` I call

```
$fun:(char * (*reverseIO)(char * ))(strTest)
```

I get several errors:

```
 error: use of undeclared identifier 'reverseIO'
              $fun:(char (*reverseIO)(char * ))(strTest)
                           ^
```

Could anyone help me get this right?

Update:
I finally got it working with proper C function pointer syntax.

```
  [C.block| void {
           c_func($fun:(char* (*reverseIO)(char*)));
                         } |]
```

But still I have the type problem:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘BS.ByteString’ with ‘GHC.Ptr.Ptr CChar’
  Expected type: GHC.Ptr.Ptr CChar -> IO (GHC.Ptr.Ptr CChar)
    Actual type: BS.ByteString -> IO BS.ByteString
```

Comment: You want your C code to call a Haskell function?  I haven't used inline-c before and had thought it was only for calling _out_ to C and not back.  Ignoring that, have you already `foreign export`ed your `reverseIO` function?  When GHC compiles Haskell the functions do not directly translate to symbols so without a foreign export there will be no `reverseIO` symbol at link time or prototype for compiling.

Comment: I'm not familiar with inline-c but `String` is not `char *`. Perhaps you need to use bytestrings, which seem to be supported by inline-c. Beware that passing (byte)strings may require to deal with C-level allocation.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Yes I use inline-c to call a GUI library(Dear imgui) only.  The rest of the stuff I'd like to do in Haskell and call those Haskell functions in C.  Regarding Foreign export as you have mentioned, I didn't see this in the fpcomplete tutorial: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/05/inline-c . But let me dig deeper in this direction. Thanks

Comment: @chi Good point, I've switched to BS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
import           Data.Monoid           ((<>))
import           Foreign.C.String
import qualified Language.C.Inline.Cpp as C

C.context (C.cppCtx <> C.baseCtx  <>C.funCtx)

C.include "pageturnerui.cpp"

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
  let reverseIO :: CString -> IO CString
      reverseIO cs = peekCString cs >>= return. reverse >>= newCString

  [C.block| void {
      pageturnerui($fun:(char* (*reverseIO)(char *)));
                         } |]
```

In my pageturnerui.cpp:

```
int pageturnerui(char* (*foo)(char*))
{
...
            static char strTest[128] = "Hello, Haskell!";

            if (ImGui::Button("Button")) {
              strcpy(strTest, foo(strTest));
            }
...
}
```

PS: My code doesn't illustrate the best practice. I'm not experienced enough to be able to provide advice on that. Just showing that it compiles and works and didn't crash.

Comment: Would you mind adding some minimal working code for `pageturnerui.cpp`?  This answer could be very valuable to people getting started with inline-c-cpp.

Comment: @luqui Done. Hope this is useful.